# Failure adding assembly to the cache: Invalid file or assembly name. The name of the file must be the name of the assembly plus .dll or .exe?

Tags: c#, windows, facebook

I am trying to add in the Facebook SDK binaries but I keep getting this error. The file is Facebook.Main.dll and gacutil does not let me add it. I already generated a KEYS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you need to sign the assembly with the generated key file.
For example

```
sn.exe -R YourAssembly.dll YourKey.snk
```

Comment: I get: `Facebook.Main.dll does not represent a strongly named assembly`. The keys file is FBControls.keys